# Не обязательно - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Встречаю разное написание. Так в каких случаях слитно, а в каких раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть противопоставление (не обязательно, а желательно) или так называемые слова-магниты (вовсе (отнюдь, совсем) не обязательно), то пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 15):

При утверждении слитно, при отрицании раздельно:

- *Не обязательно давать ответ немедленно* - отрицаю обязательность ответа.
- *Для того, чтобы все было хорошо, необязательно наличие опыта* - утверждаю "необязательность", т. е. отсутствие необходимости опыта.
- *А вот это делать не обязательно!* - отрицаю обязательность, необходимость.
- *Это условие (каково?) необязательно для решения данной задачи* - утверждаю необязательность.

Comment: Нелогично. Откуда информация о таком правиле?

Comment: Из Правил, вестимо: https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/72/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: А как отличить утверждение и отрицание? Например: *Для того, чтобы все было хорошо, необязательно наличие опыта* – отрицаю обязательность наличия опыта

Answer (score 5):

Авторы академического справочника по орфографии и пунктуации дают следующую рекомендацию: ПИШУЩИЙ ДОЛЖЕН ОТДАВАТЬ СЕБЕ ОТЧЕТ В ТОМ, ЧТО ОН ХОЧЕТ ВЫРАЗИТЬ: отрицание признака — и тогда написать НЕ отдельно от следующего слова (напр.: он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, не случайно, не существенно, не удивительно, не демократическим путём), или утверждение признака — и тогда написать НЕ слитно (ср.: он нездоров, нередки случаи, неважно, неслучайно, несущественно, неудивительно, недемократическим путем). От выбора написания будет зависеть и понимание написанного читающими (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006. § 149).